# Subversion repository gap I need to fill

Tags: svn

I have a situation where my main subversion machine died. I have resorted to an older machine.

My latest checkout is version 240, but the old machine is only up to version 200? Subversion won't let me checkin and I need help fixing the gap.

Comment: Might you or someone else have made a checkout using `git-svn` at some point? By default, that will gather and store all the svn history in git.

Comment: @Greg: no, it was caused by a complicated disk failure.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that using `git-svn` would have *caused* this problem. What I meant to suggest was that an existing checkout using `git-svn` would have *copied your complete history*, making recovery much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

1) Check out version 200 from the old machine into a new working copy.

2) Use `svn export` to copy the changes from your old working copy across to your new working copy.

3) Check the changes in as version 201 on the old machine.

You'll lose the history between versions 200 and 240, but unless you have a backup of them somewhere else then you might not be able to avoid that.